# Windows Update API - Report Client Status

Tags: c#, windows, windows-update

I have an application that uses WSUS client API to download and install updates. I have been trying to figure out how to report the client's status to the server once installs are complete, without having to run: `wuauclt /detectnow` from the command line.

The update log in C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.txt does show the reporting event: 0 Success Pre-Deployment Check Reporting Client Status

So it seems that there is a way to report the status, I just can't find it in the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know much about these APIs (maybe it would be helpful if you clarify what exactly you're doing), but this looks promising:

From the [Windows Update Agent (WUA) API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387292(v=VS.85).aspx):

- [IDownloadProgress Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385871(v=VS.85).aspx)
  Seems like you can obtain this from [IDownloadJob::GetProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385865(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [IInstallationProgress Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa386040(v=VS.85).aspx)
  Seems like you can obtain this from [IInstallationJob::GetProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385927(v=VS.85).aspx)

If you don't want to keep polling these objects for new progress, it looks like there is also the following, which your code can implement:

- [IDownloadCompletedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385858(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [IDownloadProgressChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385872(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [IInstallationCompletedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385907(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [IInstallationProgressChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa386041(v=VS.85).aspx)

I don't know if this is what you're asking for, but this is my guess.  Hope that helps.